# how to perform like and ilike quey against enum datatype column in prisma

Tags: enums, prisma

How to perform like and ilike queries against the ENUM datatype column in Prisma?
Is this possible in Prisma, If anyone knows please let me know?
I have tried several ways how to implement this in Prisma. But it doesn't work for me

```
const {role} = req.query
await this.prisma.user.findMany({
   where:{
     role: { contains: role, mode: 'insensitive']=}
   }
}
```

In my user table, the column role is enum datatype. if the query string is not matched with one of the role enums, Prisma throws the error.

```
enum Role {
  Admin
  Engineer
  Sales_User @map("Sales User")
  Customer
}
```

In my scenario, the query string role may and may not be matched with the enum Role. if the query string role will not be matched with one of the Role enums, Prisma throws the errors.

Comment: I guess, this contradicts a bit the idea of an `enum`. Maybe use a relation instead? I.e. create a table with roles (`id`, `title`) and add `roleId` to `User`.